# how to parse a string into real equation in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, mathml

I am trying to develop a model in netlogo, in which user can enter the equation for change in some variables. My question is what could be the best way to get equation input and how should i parse it and calculate results. looking for something like "mathml" which could work in netlogo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution that doesn't involve MathML or anything of the sort would be to have your users directly enter NetLogo expressions and run those using [`runresult`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/run.html), which can take a string of NetLogo code and execute it.

Here is a simple example that uses an input box widget (with the type "String (reporter)") to allow the user to enter an arbitrary mathematical expression. The button prints the result of running the expression in the output box:

[image]

In a real world application, of course, you would have to be very [careful](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/carefully.html) about error handling.

Comment: run-result command would helpful for string evaluation. but before evaluation i need to parse the string to get values from list. i.e
suppose i have three lists, L-utility, g-utility, grp-utility

Comment: Actually I have three lists, L-utility, g-utility, grp-utility
Each of these list contains value for local, global and group level attributes of an agent at timepoint 0. I want user to enter the equation for change in utility with time e.g equation for change can be L1 + L3*L4/G3. for evaluating this string, L1 should be item 1 of l-utility, L3 be item 3 of l-utility and G3 be item 3 of g-utility list. kindly guide me how can i do this. after parsing this string i can use run-result for evaluation.

Comment: @Maria: I think this warrants a separate question. I don't have time to look at it now, but someone else might be able to help.