# How to construct a string input into equation in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, equation

I need to parse the string to get values from list. i.e suppose i have three lists, L-utility, g-utility, grp-utility. Each of these list contains value for local, global and group level attributes of an agent at timepoint i. I want user to enter the equation for change in utility with time e.g equation for change can be L1 + L3*L4/G3. for evaluating this string, L1 should be item 1 of l-utility, L3 be item 3 of l-utility and G3 be item 3 of g-utility list. kindly guide me how can I do this. after parsing this string i can use run-result for evaluation.

Comment: is the question about parsing string into equation, in which case the answer you have already been given at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295683/how-to-parse-a-string-into-real-equation-in-netlogo is appropriate? Or is the problem that you don't know how to construct the string to parse?

Comment: i need to know how to construct the equation in the scenario i have described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's tricky, here's one approach that should work but is pretty inflexible. Most importantly, it relies on the string space gaps (" ") to parse the different units in the string input, so your input format would have to be "L1 + G2 + GRP3"- you can't have missing spaces or extra spaces between the letter and number.

```
globals [ L-utility G-utility GRP-utility calc-val ]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  set L-utility [ 1 2 3 4 5]
  set G-utility [ 40 50 60 70 80 ]
  set GRP-utility [ 777 889 999 1111 2222 ]

end

to splitstring-calc 

  let tokens.list []
  let to.parse string-input
  let built.string "" 

  let full.len length to.parse
  let shortened length remove " " to.parse
  let space.count full.len - shortened
  let token.count ( space.count + 1 )
  let items.list ( range 0 token.count )
  let substart 0
  let subend position " " string-input

  foreach ( range 0 token.count ) [ 
    i ->
    ifelse position " " to.parse != false [
      set subend position " " to.parse
    ]
    [
      set subend length to.parse
    ]
    let cur.token substring to.parse substart subend
    set tokens.list lput ( remove " " cur.token ) tokens.list
    set to.parse substring to.parse ( subend ) ( length to.parse )
    if length to.parse > 0 and item 0 to.parse = " " [
      set to.parse remove-item 0 to.parse
    ]      
  ]

  foreach tokens.list [
    i -> 
    ifelse member? i "+ - / * ( ) " [
      set built.string ( word built.string " " i " " )
    ]
    [
      let l.name substring i 0 (length i - 1)
      let l.num last i
      set built.string ( word built.string " item " l.num " " l.name "-utility " )
    ]
  ]

  set built.string remove-item 0 built.string
  print built.string
  set calc-val run-result built.string    

end
```

You can then use an input box of type "string" to write your equations and it should work:
[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]
[image: Example 3]
[image: Example 4]

Note that if you want to add more operators than I did, you should be able to just add them to the `"+ - / * ( )"` string.